# How to get the coordinates of the pixels inside an ellipse? (screenshot)

Tags: language-agnostic

I need to get the coordinates of all the pixels inside this particular region of an ellipse.

I know the size of the grid, the center of the elipse and the vertical_radix and horizontal_radix.

I searched on the math forums but couldn't find anything useful.

So for the next example the grid is 26 by 26. 
Center of the ellipse is at (13, 7) and vertical_radix is 7 and horizontal_radix = 13.

Knowing this I need the coordinates (pair of x and y) of all the grey pixels.

I just need like a function that knowing this 6 params (grid_width, grid_height, x_center, y_center, vertical_radix, horizontal_radix) could get my coordinates. (any of the tagged languages)

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is this homework? (There is a tag for it)

Comment: @jprofitt - yes just a part I couldn't work out. what do you mean there is a tag for it ?

Comment: The same way you tagged the languages, you can replace one with the "homework" tag

Comment: oh nice.. got it now :). very late hour and all I see are grey dots by now :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale the x and y offsets of the dots from the center into a unit circle, then check the distance from the center.

**EDIT:**

Assuming a center of (x, y), a point at (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>), and an ellipse with axes of (a, b):

The scaled point is (2(x<sub>1</sub>-x)/a, 2(y<sub>1</sub>-y)/b). See if this is more or less than 1 from (0, 0), i.e. square each component and compare the sum with 1.

Comment: could you develop more on the ideea. it's too summarized. like at least one example for one pixel or anything. Thanks

Comment: still not working. I worked out an example of an pixel inside the ellipse from the screenshot example. so center of the elipse (x = 13, y = 7), x1 = 2 & y1 = 4 an point inside the elipse and the axes a = 26, b = 14. I computed the scaled point = (-0.423..., -0.214). The distance between this point and the Origin (0,0) = 0.474. So its less than 1. I think I mistaken one of the parameters. Could you work just this one example for me please

Comment: Ah, I forgot that they need to be halved. My bad.