# Finding pixels inside an ellipse

Tags: graphics, pixel, ellipse

My maths skills are terrible so I don't even know where to start with this. This is for a hobby project written in C#.

To keep things simple, let's say I need to operate on all of the pixels positioned inside an ellipse. How would I get an array of the valid pixel locations inside the ellipse that I need to work with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933114/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-the-pixels-inside-an-ellipse-screenshot

Comment: this does not sound to be the right way to solve your task, if you describe your goal, i think there would be a better solution

Comment: @AlexWien I'm creating an image editor which has helped answer a lot of my curiosities about digital imaging. Specifically I'm having trouble with writing a selection tool and getting pixels to work with from an elliptical selection.

Answer (score 0):

In an ellipse the sum of the distance between a point in the ellipse and both foci is twice the major axis so:

```
PF1 + PF2 = 2a
```

Where *P* is the point, *F1* and *F2* the foci and *a* the semi major axis.

If the sum is less then 2a the point will be inside the ellispe.

[Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)

Answer (score 0):

For that task i would  recommend taking a look at [bresenhams filled circle Algorit](http://actionsnippet.com/?p=496)hm.
If you scale the y achsis you can use it to draw ellipses, too.
Bresenham algorithms work by using only integer arithmetic, which makes them  fast(est)

This works only for axe-parallel ellipses